# The number of ways of posting the letters when no letter box remains empty is?

Tags: combinatorics

> $6$ letters are to be posted in three letter boxes.The number of ways
>   of posting the letters when no letter box remains empty is?

I solved the sum like dividing into possibilities $(4,1,1),(3,2,1)$ and $(2,2,2)$ and calculated the three cases separately getting $90,360$ and $90$ respectively.

What I wanted to know is there any shortcut method to solve this problem faster?Can stars and bars be used?How?

Or can the method of coefficients be used like say finding coefficient of $t^6$ in $(t+t^2+t^3+t^4)^3$.Will that method work here?

Comment: This is not a combination with repetition since the letters are different.

Comment: When did I say it is combination with repetition ?

Comment: When you asked about using "stars and bars."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inclusion-Exclusion.

$3^6$ ways total.
$2^6$ ways if you only mail to $1\&2,2\&3$ or $1\&3$, subtract them off (3 alike cases).
$1^6$ way if you only mail to $1$, or to $2$, or to $3$, add them back in because they were subtracted twice (agai, 3 cases all alike).

$3^6 - 3 \cdot 2^6 + 3 \cdot 1^6$

Answer (score 2):

[Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind): your particular example of six letters and 3 letterboxes has a solution of $3! \,S_2(6,3) = 6 \times 90 =540$ possible surjections, the same as the result you found

Using exponential generating functions, you could find the coefficient of $x^6$ in the expansion of $(e^x-1)^3$ and multiply that by $6!$ to get $\frac34 \times 720= 540$

Comment: Going over my head :-P! Anyway thanks

Answer (score -1):

Ways of dividing in 3 and 3 are 6!/3!3!=20.
3 are directly given in the letter box . 3 are left number of ways from that is 3*3*3=27 as there are three options for each letter.
Total ways =27*20=540

Comment: This logic is completely wrong.  That it came up with the same final number is purely a fluke.  Compare to the problem of seven letters and three boxes and you will see that it gives the wrong value.  The correct value for seven letters 3 boxes would be $3^7-3\cdot 2^7+3 = {7\brace 3}\cdot 3! = 1806$.  The logic in this answer would have you believe it would be $\binom{7}{3}\cdot 3^4$ or similar.