# Finding the number of ways of posting six letters in three letter boxes such that no letter box remains empty.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, stirling-numbers, balls-in-bins

> Find the number of ways of posting six letters in three letter boxes such that no letter box remains empty.

This question already has answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610616/the-number-of-ways-of-posting-the-letters-when-no-letter-box-remains-empty-is). But my doubt is in the following method.

$$^6C_3\times3^3$$

Is the above method correct or is it just accidental that the answer is coming correct?

Also, shouldn't we be doing $^6P_3$ instead of $^6C_3$ because we would want to arrange the letters too?

Comment: Purely coincidental.  Imagine if you will seven letters and three boxes.  What would you have thought the answer would have been in that case?  $\binom{7}{3}3^4=2835$?  That is wrong.  The correct answer is as stated before ${7 \brace 3} 3! = 1806$ with the brace referring to the stirling number of the second kind.  Equivalently, $3^7-3\cdot 2^7+3\cdot 1^7 = 1806$

Comment: The reason why $~^6P_3 \cdot 3^3$ is wrong is because you incorrectly apply some significance as to which the "*first*" letter in each box was when that should have been ignored and forgotten.  The logic behind $~^6C_3\cdot 3^3$ is wrong for the same reason in addition to as you say that the first three letters chosen are not being arranged.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you. I'll think more on it and may reply back after a few hours.

Comment: With $n$ letters and $k$ boxes, the correct answer is ${n\brace k} k!$ seen by splitting the $n$ letters up into $k$ nonempty piles, and then choosing which box to put each pile in.  The answer of $\binom{n}{k}k^{n-k}$ is the number of ways to choose $k$ "*original*" letters to use for each box, and specifically having those original letters be in "*ascending order*", then assigning the remaining letters to boxes.  Not only should there not be a requirement that the "original letters" be in ascending order, there shouldn't be a concept of "original letters" in the first place.

Comment: It just so happened to be that the undercounting mistake caused by putting the "original letters" in "ascending order" happened to perfectly cancel out the overcounting mistake of having "original letters" in the first place for the case of $n=6,k=3$.  That was purely a fluke.  They do not so perfectly cancel each other out with different values of $n,k$